# Failed a review audit. Was it a bad audit?

Tags: discussion, review-audits, specific-audit

I was going through the "First Posts" queue and I got this question that turned out to be an audit.
https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/27295018
The question consists of an image and a description (only one sentence) that I feel is very poor and needs to be expanded.

Because of that, I flagged this question as "Needs details or clarity" and I was very surprised when it turned out that it was an audit that I failed.
I just started with reviewing yesterday (have not done it for like a year), and this is not the first "suspicious" audit that I failed in this short time.

Maybe something changed in between that made questions like this one acceptable?

Comment: It's one of those cases. Since GCloud experienced some "internal" issues, many users encountered this error a couple days ago. Lots of upvotes for a bad question. Audits are selected automatically, and the upvote deluge made it look like a "good question" to the system. The question has been closed now, so it's not going to be an audit anymore.

Comment: This might help https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/157121/what-are-review-tests-audits-and-how-do-they-work